# Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am getting the following error

> TS2786: 'Letters' cannot be used as a JSX component.
> Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element.
> Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

which I do not understand

```
// Letters.tsx
import React from 'react';

const Letters = () => {
    const _renderletters = ():JSX.Element[] => {
        return ["a", "b"].map((letter: string, index:number):JSX.Element => {
            return <p key={index}>{letter}</p>
        })
    }
    return _renderletters()
}

export default Letters;


// UseLetters.tsx
import React from 'react'
import Letters from "./Letters";

const UseLetters = () => {
    return <Letters /> // <- this is highlighted with the error
}

export default UseLetters;
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been blind. This

```
// Letters.tsx
import React from 'react';

const Letters = () => {
    const _renderletters = ():JSX.Element[] => {
        return ["a", "b"].map((letter: string, index:number):JSX.Element => {
            return <p key={index}>{letter}</p>
        })
    }
    return _renderletters()
}

export default Letters;
```

Currently returns an `array`, which must be wrapped into something, i.e. a Fragment

```
  return <>{_renderletters()}</>
```